# How can i convert an opportunity to a custom object using process builder

Tags: custom-object, opportunity, custom, convert

I'm looking to convert opp product lines to a custom object 'assigned products' using the process builder with the opportunity closing being the trigger to create the new record is this possible via the process builder or would I have to use apex triggers?

Answer (score 0):

To clone the records you can use Process Builder, however to be able to delete the old ones (which is what you mean by convert I presume), you would have to use either a **flow** (that you can trigger from within your process) or **apex**.